# Appcelerator sqlite not throwing errors

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite, titanium, appcelerator

I just created a new Alloy project for iPad only and added the following code to alloy.js:

```
Alloy.Globals.Database = Ti.Database.install("database/nonexistanfddsfsdfsdft.db", "wtfisgoingdsfsdon");
Alloy.Globals.DatabaseName = "wtfisgoingonsdfds";
```

Obviously that location does not exist as I was attempting to get Appcelerator to throw an error letting me know that file location doesn't exist.  In previous versions this is exactly what happened.  However with this new project there is no error and Appcelerator happily goes along as if nothing is wrong.

My SDK is **6.0.2.GA**

My appcelerator build is: Appcelerator Studio, **build: 4.8.1.201612050850**

Is this a change to appcelerator or is something funky going on? As a side note I did this because when I tried to set up everything correctly items were simply not being inserted into my database and no errors were being thrown.

Any help would be appreciated.

CJ

Comment: I think errors are shown in Ti SDK 5.5.1 or lower. But not sure about 6.0.2 as haven't upgrade it yet.

Comment: I actually found this post: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-4748 that kind of explains what is going on.

Comment: Pretty confirm it is.